# using Python and SQL

Tags: python, sql

I used txt files to store data in it and read it any time i need and search in it and append and delete from it 
so 
why should i use database i can still using txt files ?

Comment: Yes. Why would anyone need a database?

Comment: Check here. I got so many reasons  - https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ms-android-lenovo&biw=360&bih=299&ei=fHvVV9WSGonbvgT79KjgDw&q=why+database+is+required&oq=why+database&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.1.0l5.2464.9482.0.10713.40.27.0.5.5.0.394.6105.0j10j11j5.26.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-serp..31.9.1219.3..41j0i67k1j0i131k1.njS8k059fEQ

Comment: Speed? Multiple access keys? Multiple users? Consistent data? Backups and rollback logs? To name just a few

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you have used files instead of a database. To answer the question, let us check the advantages of using a database:

- **it is faster**: a service is awaiting commands and your app sends some commands to it. Database Management Systems have a lot of cool stuff implemented which you will be lacking if you use a single file. True, you can create a service which loads the file into memory and serves commands, but while that seems to be easy, it will be inferior to RDBMS's, since your implementation is highly unlikely to be even close to a match of the optimizations done for RDBMS's over decades, unless you implement an RDBMS, but then you end up with an RDBMS, after all
- **it is safer**: RDBMS's encrypt data and have user-password authentication along with port handling
- **it is smaller**: data is stored in a compressed manner, so if you end up with a lot of data, data size will get critical much later
- **it is developed**: you will always have possibilities to upgrade your system with juices implemented recently and to keep up the pace with science's current development
- you can use ORM's and other stuff built to ease the pain of data handling
- **it supports concurrent access**: imagine the case when many people are reaching your database at the same time. Instead of you implementing very complicated stuff, you can get this feature instantly

All in all, you will either use a database management system (not necessarily relational), implement your own or work with textual files. Your textual file will quickly be overwhelmed if your application is successful and you will need a database management system. If you write your own, you might have a success story to tell, but it will come only after many years of hard work. So, if you get successful, then you will need database management system. If you do not get successful, you can use textual files, but the question is: is it worth it?

And finally, your textual file is a database, but you are managing it by your custom and probably very primitive (no offence, but it is virtually impossible to achieve results when you are racing against the whole world) database management system compared to the ones out there. So, yes, you should learn to use advanced database management systems and should refactor your project to use one.

Comment: Down-votes are always welcome, since downvotes have the intention to point the author of a post to the right direction. However, in this case I am not sure why this post was downvoted and why.

Comment: Thank you i am sure i understood and i will use database instead of txt files and me too i dont know why this post had down-votes i hope i could vote.

Comment: @MahmoudHamdy, you are certainly welcome. If the answer made things clear, then you might want to accept it. However, if the downvoter has a valid point in downvoting, then I will edit the answer to improve it. So far I do not see any problems with it though.